# How does the Below Java Type casting works?

Tags: java, casting

How does the output turn out to be '1'?

```
long number = 499_999_999_000_000_001L;    
double converted = (double) number;
System.out.println(number - (long) converted);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow works best with a single question per post. Which of the questions are you interested in? Please give more context to it - would you expect the code not to compile? Or are you asking about the execution-time handling? At the moment the question isn't clear.

Comment: I can understand the second question, but what do you mean by "how does this typecasting works"? `double` to and from `long` are both valid casts, as specified in the language specification. There is nothing to explain here...

Comment: @Sweeper I can't understand how does the output returns 1?

Comment: You expect it to return zero, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: It's because of overflow bits**

If you check java documentation [Double.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE). You will observe that max double integer value supported by java is 2^53 ≅ 10^16 but your value becomes (4.99999999 * 10^17) after typecasting which is outside the range of double so because of overflow it is rounded. For better understanding run this code.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long longNumber = 499_999_999_000_000_001L;
        double doubleNumber = (double) longNumber;
        long longConverted = (long)doubleNumber;
        System.out.println(longNumber+" "+doubleNumber+" "+longConverted);
    }
}
```

Its output will be:

```
499999999000000001 4.99999999E17 499999999000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is a little "debugging".
Try running this code...

```java
long number = 499_999_999_000_000_001L;
System.out.println(number);
double converted = (double) number;
System.out.println(converted);
System.out.println((long) converted);
System.out.println(number - (long) converted);
```

This is what it displays...

```
499999999000000001
4.99999999E17
499999999000000000
1
```

Do you want to know why the conversion back to `long` from `double` drops the `1`?
If you do then I refer you to the [java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

### EDIT

To be precise, refer to section [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> A widening primitive conversion from ... **long to double**, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).

Comment: thanks for the answer but I still have a doubt as both long and double are 8byte so why does (long) converted turns out to be 499999999000000000 and not 499999999000000001?

Comment: All programming languages interpret the bits of a `long` and a `double` differently, because a `long` is an integral value and a `double` is not. You will find many online articles explaining the difference, for example [Floating-point arithmetic](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077257/floating-point-arithmetic.html). You can also refer to the _Java Virtual Machine_ (JVM) specification which I provided a link to in my answer.